# Add days to a dataitem date field in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

How to increment a single day from a dataitem bound to a Gridview TemplateField?

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%>
```

**RESULT**

13/05/16

**DESIRED RESULT**

14/05/16

I am trying to achieve this on the aspx page and not from code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")).AddDays(1) %>
```

Comment: I tried some variations of add days. I knew it was simple. Thanks Arvin. Do you also know how I could output the day e.g "Friday"?

Comment: this code  should do it !  <%# Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")).AddDays(1).DayOfWeek %>